# C# not finding correct file path

Tags: c#, email, email-attachments

I have a C# console application that sends Excel spreadsheet attachments through email.

I have given the file path in `App.config`.  While trying to find the file, the code looks at proper location. But when trying to attach the file inside the `foreach` statement, it is looking in code's `bin` folder.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FilePath"));
        FileInfo[] folderFiles = null;
        folderFiles = dir1.GetFiles();



    foreach (FileInfo aFile in folderFiles)
           {


                 message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(aFile.Name));
           }
```

Comment: What is the value of `aFile.Name` in the loop? Look at it in the debugger. There's no path, is there? When you provide a path, it looks in the path you provide. When you don't, it doesn't. What does this suggest to you?

Comment: I have provided the FilePath of the directory it has look into. Then in ForEach loop, I'm asking it to look into the files in the directory.

Comment: Use the watch window in the debugger to examine the value of aFile.Name at runtime. Set a breakpoint and use the debugger. I already understand exactly what you are doing, as well as what you mistakenly think your code is doing instead. I am trying to help YOU understand exactly what you are doing, but you have to participate.

Comment: What's `message`?

Comment: @SaraDob Compare [FileInfo.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx) and [FileInfo.FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: FileNot Found Exception. Thats because it is trying to find it in bin directory of the code base. Not from the file path i have given in App.config. The "dir1 " shows the correct path.

Comment: Thanks  Andrew Morton , The FileInfo.FullName part That Nailed It. Thanks all for taking a look at the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`aFile.FullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) (includes the full path) rather than [`aFile.Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx) (only the filename). If a command is not doing what you expect, you should check the documentation.

Alternatively, you could make it simpler:

```
string dir1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FilePath");
foreach(string aFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir1))
{
    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(aFile));
}
```

as [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.1) simply returns the full filenames and you would have to think about not doing so (e.g. by using `Path.GetFileName`) to do otherwise.